# C# Regular expression for skipping words that starts with some characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find and replace some words from a string. But I want to skip words containing special characters like '`@,#,?,!`' etc. I have written one but the problem is it selects first bracket also.

Example 1:
    `(Victoria Basement OR QVB @Victoria Basement #Victoria Basement ?#Victoria Basement!?)`

**Update:**
Example 2:
    `(Victoria Basement OR QVB @Victoria Basement #Victoria Basement ?#Victoria Basement!? Victoria Basement@ Victoria Basement's`

Regex: 
    `[^#@?!%$&]Victoria Basement`

Expected output: it should select only "`Victoria Basement`" not "`(Victoria Basement`" or "`@Victoria Basement #Victoria Basement ?#Victoria Basement!?`"

Comment: Share some C# code here.

Comment: from the way you've asked vs the way you stated your results, it sounds like you want to capture words with special characters around them. Otherwise, why would you use regex for this, instead of string.Replace()?

Comment: Thumper, no I can't use only replace. The picture is bigger to explain here. BTW I have updated my question again. Can you please answer for example 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this: `((?<![#@\?!%$&])Victoria Basement)`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/tV1rV5/1

[EDIT] add explanation:

So `[^#@?!%$&]Victoria Basement` will capture 1 character for `[^#@?!%$&]` but in case of `(Victoria Basement` it won't be matching so you need to do a "[negative look behind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)" to exclude that character from the match like `(?<![#@\?!%$&])` then you wrap everything with `()` if you want to capture! ;)

Comment: Thanks it helps, ((?<![#@\?!%$&])Victoria Basement \b)

Comment: Hi Antoni, can you please help me for the following scenarios : (Victoria Basement OR QVB @Victoria Basement #Victoria Basement ?#Victoria Basement!? Victoria Basement@ Victoria Basement's

Comment: If i understand well you don't want to match this case `@ Victoria Basement's`. So you can add the case in the current list with a `|` that means OR. `((?<![#@\?!%$&]|@\s)Victoria Basement)`